# Need help setting up Apache on CentOS 5.5 , getting 403

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, centos

I have purchased a VPS and I have done everything described here (version 2.2.17) : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html

I have apache running, but I can not view the page in browser. Chrome says : Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ... and when I

```
lynx localhost
```

I get

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

I tried `chmod 744 htdocs/index.html` but still nothing.

Apache is running `httpd (pid 7638) already running`

And here is the conf/httpd.conf file https://gist.github.com/875352

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do all directories leading up to your htdocs directory have public read?

Comment: Nope! its in /root/workspace/apache and the root folder : drwxr-x---  4 root root 4096 Mar 17 23:19 root . I wonder if I can move the whole thing in another folder

Comment: It seems strange to me to be serving files out of `root`'s home directory. Maybe rather than fix your permissions problem, move them to `/var/www/` or `/home/daemon/` or something? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all directories up to and including your htdocs directory have public read. :)

Comment: thanks, this solved this problem. having another problem but i shall try to figure that one out