# Apache only accessible from localhost but not via IP or Domain Name

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, centos

So I was having problem setting up my Apache and I have it running now.

If you want to see my httpd.conf file or some other info please look at [Need help setting up Apache on CentOS 5.5 , getting 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346479/need-help-setting-up-apache-on-centos-5-5-getting-403)

I can successfully run `lynx localhost` and see "It works!" however when I try to access the site via the domain name or IP address I do not get anything. Chrome says oops could not connect to blah blah.

Here is my `iptables -L` : https://gist.github.com/875450

Here is my `iptables-save` : https://gist.github.com/875472

So what am doing wrong that I can see it locally but not via the IP?

Thanks

Comment: Do us all a favour, and post the output of `iptables-save`. `iptables -L` mangles the rules so much that they are unreadable

Comment: Can you ping or ssh to the domain name from the same place where you're trying to run the (remote?) web browser?

Comment: What does `netstat -anp | grep -i apache` look like? (Assuming the process is named `apache`; grep for `httpd` or whatever it is named.)

Comment: there https://gist.github.com/875472

Comment: netstat results : https://gist.github.com/875478

Comment: i can both ping and `ssh root@domain.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with your iptables configuration. The first rule in the `INPUT` chain is:

```
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
```

and all other rules in the chain are appended (`-A`) after it. But the last rule in the `RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` chain is:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

which rejects any connection that has not been accepted previously, including any HTTP connections.

You need to insert (`-I`) the HTTP/HTTPS rules to the `INPUT` chain instead of appending (`-A`) them, so that they are applied first.

Comment: awesome that did it, how can i remove the ones i appended?

Comment: @moe: use `iptables -D INPUT <rule-number>`. Rules are numbered starting at `1`.